# error al instalar sql server 2008 express en una maquina virtual

Tags: sql

Hola buenos dias una pregunta cree una maquina virtual con windows 7 para utilizar sql 2008 express pero al instalar me marco el siguiente error:

> "El compilador de MOF no se pudo conectar con el servidor WMI. Esto se
>   puede deber a un error semántico como una incompatibilidad con el
>   repositorio WMI o a un error real como que no se ha iniciado el
>   servidor WMI".

Alguien que me oriente porfavor ya realice varias cosas pero sigue igual.

Gracias

Comment: Hola Carlos, puedes complementar qué soluciones has intentado realizar, para evitar repetir las soluciones que ya has intentado. Te dejo el siguiente enlace con soluciones a errores comunes de instalación de sql: http://basedotaspartii.blogspot.mx/2012/06/errores-comunes-al-instalar-sql-server.html

Comment: Revisa con la utilidad [`WMI Diagnosis Utility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa394603(VS.85).aspx). En mi opinión, el problema no está relacionado a programación, ya que el problema en sí es del SO. [Introducción a WMI](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc753534(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: gracias por su respuesta , intente  ejecutar el programa que menciona  Davlio y en  pero ese programa solo se puede ocupar en un sistema operativo de 64 bits  porque en el mio no funciono es de 32bits  otra  opcion que intente  fue el  desinstalar lo que tenia  instalado   y volverlo a instalar pero  me manda  otro error "error: can't find registro key:SOFTWARE/Microsoft/MSDTC   tambien  lo estoy checando

Comment: una duda como les comentaba estoy intentando instalar el sql en una maquina virtual windows 7 32 bits y ando utilizando  un sistema  operativo ligero segun lo baje no creen que tambien  tenga que ver con eso  gracias

Comment: ya  lo solucione el sistema operativo le faltan cosas  lo cambie y ya quedo gracias  por su ayuda

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, al intentar instalar sql Server Express. Me gustaría saber qué es lo que le faltaba al S.O